# Bootstrap data-interval malfunctioning

Tags: javascript

I get an error in the `data-interval` time. Despite I setup it at 5000000... ms, it just slideshow too fast... 
can't find the solution... any ideas would be helpful thanks!

```html
<div class="Slideshow">
  <div id="carusel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="50000000">
    
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
  
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="assets/img/1.jpg" alt="immagine1">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/img/2.jpg" alt="immagine2">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/img/3.jpg" alt="immagine3">
      </div>

      
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How fast? I could not wait for 50,000 secs. This seemed pretty slow to me:
http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/qpACUHKwRs

Comment: fast that the time the picture is shown is not comparable to 50.000secs...

Comment: i mean... the picture is shown for about .4 sec before the transition effect kicks in.. but i'm startin to think the problem is not in the html code, but in the bootstrap.css or in it's .js

Comment: i managed to find the default time setted  in the .js and it's 5000 sec, but the pictures does not stay there for that time...